# How can I use Sphinx to render from a python script

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have one single sphinx specific rst-file and would like to render it as HTML using Sphinx from within a python script. When searching for solutions all I can find is the command line interface to Sphinx.

The answer to this question [Python convert sphinx RST to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198604/python-convert-sphinx-rst-to-html) doesn't work and seems very hackish to me.

I am imagining something like this:

```py
import sphinx
sphinx.render(rst_file='myfile.rst', output_file='myfile.html')
```

Comment: Is it something like this you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657926/407651